# Reverse order only of divs with same class inside other divs

Tags: javascript

My problem is here: http://jsfiddle.net/9vhobdw7/2/

```html
<div class="c-container">
  <div>Container 4
    <div>my div 4</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>Container 3
    <div>my div 3</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>Container 2
    <div>my div 2</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>Container 1
    <div>my div 1</div>
    <div class="item">1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to have **only** the divs with class="item" in reverse order, from bottom to top. Other divs need to be the same. Like this:

```html
<div class="c-container">
  <div>Container 4
    <div>my div 4</div>
    <div class="item">1</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>Container 3
    <div>my div 3</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>Container 2
    <div>my div 2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>Container 1
    <div>my div 1</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Actually in the divs class="item" I have a call from divs from external URL with function load:eq(n).

I've tried with CSS, .each().reverse(), Array, replaceWith() and more functions but nothing, have no significant result.

Edit, add task.
Now, if the task includes more classes, with divs inside to reverse as

```
<div class="c-container">
<div>Container 6
<div>my div 6</div>
<div class="item2">3</div>
</div>
<br>
<div>Container 5
<div>my div 5</div>
<div class="item1">1</div>
</div>
<br>
<div>Container 4
<div>my div 4</div>
<div class="item2">2</div>
</div>
<br>
<div>Container 3
<div>my div 3</div>
<div class="item2">1</div>
</div>
<br>
<div>Container 2
<div>my div 2</div>
<div class="item1">2</div>
</div>
<br>
<div>Container 1
<div>my div 1</div>
<div class="item1">3</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have to duplicate the function changing the variables names and classes names? I've tried this

```
const children1 = document.querySelectorAll('.c-container .item1');
const reverse1 = [...children1].reverse();
children1.forEach((item, i) => item.outerHTML = reverse1[i].outerHTML);
            
const children2 = document.querySelectorAll('.c-container .item2');
const reverse2 = [...children2].reverse();
children2.forEach((item, i) => item.outerHTML = reverse2[i].outerHTML);
```

which works, but it seems redundant.

Comment: Please show the code you've tried so far in the question here on Stack Overflow, not just on jsFiddle. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` on the editor toolbar) to use an interface much like jsFiddle's.

Comment: It's great that you listed the functions you used in your attempts, but it would be even better if you could edit your question with the **full** code of your _less worst_ attempt.

Comment: @ro_Dif you cannot call array methods on elementsByClassName because they are an HTMLCollection, not an array...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution, not really swapping divs, just swapping content:

```
var items=document.getElementsByClassName("item");
var length=items.length;
for(var i=0; i<Math.floor(length/2); i++) {
  var temp=items[i].innerHTML;
  items[i].innerHTML=items[length-i-1].innerHTML;
  items[length-i-1].innerHTML=temp;
}
```

`items` and `length` are helper `var`s.
`innerHTML` can be replaced with `innerText`.
etc...
Edit: fixed with `Math.floor(length/2)`.  (There's an extra swap when `length` is odd...)

Comment: Very nice, efficient answer.

Comment: More "elegant" might be with cloning, children, etc - but I went for "working"...

Comment: First line in `for` loop can be: `console.log("swap "+i+" with "+(length-i-1));` - for logging what is swapped with what...  :) :) :)

Comment: Does this answer help you?
If so - please select and up-vote it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `innerHtml` for div with class `item`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var listItems = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('item')).map(i=>i.cloneNode(true))
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('item')).forEach((item,index)=>{
      item.innerHTML = listItems[listItems.length-index-1].innerHTML
    })
});
```

See full example in the playground: http://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/7uhmzbct/23/

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt be trying to reverse the divs... You are trying to reverse what those divs display.  So, you can build an array of the contents of the "item" divs themselves.  Then reverse the order of that array and then replace the innerHTML of your "item" divs.

Example below...  it is not the most effecient code because it iterates over your list twice...  but for the purposes of showing what you need to do to accomplish what it sounds like you're wanting, I think its more illustrative.

```js
function reverseItemContents() {
  var itemDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
  var contentList = [];
  var index;
  for (index = 0; index < itemDivs.length; index++) {
    contentList.push(itemDivs[index].innerHTML);
  }
  contentList.reverse();
  for (index = 0; index < itemDivs.length; index++) {
    itemDivs[index].innerHTML = contentList[index];
  }
}
```

```html
<button onClick="reverseItemContents()">Reverse Content</button>
<div class="c-container">
  <br>
  <div>Container 4
    <div>my div 4</div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/Eo_circle_blue-grey_white_number-4.svg" width="130"></div>
  </div>

  <br>
  <div>Container 3
    <div>my div 3</div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/NYCS-bull-trans-3.svg/1024px-NYCS-bull-trans-3.svg.png" width="130"></div>
  </div>

  <br>
  <div>Container 2
    <div>my div 2</div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d8/Icon_2_red.svg" width="130"></div>
  </div>

  <br>
  <div>Container 1
    <div>my div 1</div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f4/Icon_1_%28set_orange%29.png" width="130"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My method would be to simply select them all, reverse the array, and then overwrite the original items. Using `outerHTML` means that more than just the `div`s' contents will be swapped.

```js
function reverse(selector) {
  const children = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  const reversed = [...children].reverse();
  children.forEach((item, i) => item.outerHTML = reversed[i].outerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div class="c-container">
  <div>Container 4
    <div>my div 4</div>
    <div class="item" style="background-color: tomato;">4</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>Container 3
    <div>my div 3</div>
    <div class="item" style="background-color: orange;">3</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>Container 2
    <div>my div 2</div>
    <div class="item" style="background-color: yellow;">2</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>Container 1
    <div>my div 1</div>
    <div class="item" style="background-color: lightgreen;">1</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="reverse('.c-container .item')">Reverse</button>
```

I don't really see a need to add all the extra complexity proposed by the other answers. Using an arugment will allow you to re-use the function for other sets of nodes.

Comment: Please could you explain me better how can I improve the task with several classes to reverse. I tried with the code adding arguments ('.c-container .item1, .c-container .item2'), but it doesn't display the result I need.

Comment: @ro_Dif Do you have access to edit the HTML? I would just add a new class for `.swap-me`, and select that. If you **don't**, I would use `reverse('.c-container [class^="item"]')`. I only advise doing this if you can't edit the DOM, since the `[class]` selector is less efficient than the `.` selector.

Comment: I create a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62710493/reverse-order-of-multiple-divs-with-same-class-inside-other-divs, because I thought I was not so clear here.